# Ayuda con AndroidLoginyRegistro con PHP

Tags: php, android, android-studio

Bajé un proyecto de Android que consiste en un login y registro, es el mas sencillo y fácil que encontré. La cuestión es que este proyecto para registrarse pide usuario, correo, edad y sexo pero yo solo necesito usuario y correo.
Pido la ayuda de ustedes para que me expliquen como poder hacer que el proyecto al registrarme y loguearme solo pida usuario y correo ya que si elimino las variables me empieza a dar un error de JSON y termino por dañar el proyecto.

**AppSingleton.java :**

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppSingleton {
    private static AppSingleton mAppSingletonInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mContext;

private AppSingleton(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized AppSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mAppSingletonInstance == null) {
        mAppSingletonInstance = new AppSingleton(context);
    }
    return mAppSingletonInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req,String tag) {
    req.setTag(tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
}
```

**RegisterActivity.java :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main_formulario_docente extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
private static final String URL_FOR_REGISTRATION = "http://192.168.0.110/android_login_v2/register.php";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private EditText signupInputName, signupInputEmail, signupInputPassword, signupInputPassword2, signupInputAge;
private Button btnSignUp;
private Button btnLinkLogin;
private RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formulario_docente);

    // Progress dialog
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    signupInputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    signupInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    signupInputPassword2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    //signupInputAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_age);

    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    //genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            submitForm();
        }
    });
    btnLinkLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main_docente.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void submitForm() {
    registerUser(signupInputName.getText().toString(),
            signupInputEmail.getText().toString(),
            signupInputPassword.getText().toString());
}

private void registerUser(final String name,  final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registrando ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_FOR_REGISTRATION, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {
                    String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + user +", You are successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Main_formulario_docente.this, Main_docente.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            //params.put("gender", gender);
            //params.put("age", dob);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

**LoginActivity.java :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main_docente extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final String URL_FOR_LOGIN = "http://192.168.0.110/android_login_v2/login.php";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private EditText loginInputEmail, loginInputPassword;
private Button btnlogin;
private Button btnLinkSignup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_docente);


    loginInputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    loginInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    // Progress dialog
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loginUser(loginInputEmail.getText().toString(), loginInputPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    btnLinkSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_formulario_docente.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void loginUser( final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "login";
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in...");
    showDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {
                    String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                    // Launch User activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Main_docente.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", user);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }

    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.show();
}
private void hideDialog() {
    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

**android_login_config.php :**

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "12345");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_login");

?>
```

**android_login_connect.php :**

```
<?php
class android_login_connect {
private $conn;

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'android_login_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    // return database object
    return $this->conn;
}
}

?>
```

**login.php :**

```
<?php
require_once 'update_user_info.php';
$db = new update_user_info();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// get the user by email and password
$user = $db->VerifyUserAuthentication($email, $password);

if ($user != false) {
    // use is found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try 
again!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required post params is missing
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is 
missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**register.php :**

```
<?php

require_once 'update_user_info.php';
$db = new update_user_info();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && 
isset($_POST['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// check if user is already existed with the same email
if ($db->CheckExistingUser($email)) {
    // user already existed
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->StoreUserInfo($name, $email, $password);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is 
missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**update_user_info.php :**

```
<?php

class update_user_info {

private $conn;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'android_login_connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new android_login_connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function StoreUserInfo($name, $email, $password) {
    $hash = $this->hashFunction($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO android_php_post(name, email, 
encrypted_password, salt) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, 
encrypted_password, salt FROM android_php_post WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt-> bind_result($token2,$token3,$token4,$token5);
        while ( $stmt-> fetch() ) {
           $user["name"] = $token2;
           $user["email"] = $token3;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function VerifyUserAuthentication($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, encrypted_password, 
salt FROM android_php_post WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt-> bind_result($token2,$token3,$token4,$token5);

        while ( $stmt-> fetch() ) {
           $user["name"] = $token2;
           $user["email"] = $token3;
           $user["encrypted_password"] = $token4;
           $user["salt"] = $token5;
        }

        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $token5;
        $encrypted_password = $token4;
        $hash = $this->CheckHashFunction($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function CheckExistingUser($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from android_php_post WHERE 
email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashFunction($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkHashFunction($salt, $password) {
    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    return $hash;
}

}

?>
```

**Cambios Realizados :**

Ya que muchos votaron por poner la pregunta en espera, actualice el codigo y lo que hice en los archivos `PHP` fue quitar las variables `$age` y `$gender` que como ya habia comentado, no las necesito y este proyecto trae por defecto, y el cambio que realice en `JAVA` fue en el archivo de registro, donde quite tambien las variables `gender` y `age`, aviso que el proyecto antes de hacerle cualquier cambio funcionaba al 100% pero como ya saben yo solo necesito que para registrarse se pidan `usuario`, `correo` y `password` en vez de `usuario`, `correo`, `age`, `gender` y `password`.

**Pero este es el error que arroja el logcat y no entiendo que esta mal si solo quite las variables minuciosamente que no necesitaba :**

```
04-21 08:27:41.036 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err: 
org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be 
converted to JSONObject
04-21 08:27:41.041 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
joinder.proyecto.Main_formulario_docente$3.onResponse
(Main_formulario_docente.j
ava:93)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at   
joinder.proyecto.Main_formulario_docente$3.onResponse
(Main_formulario_docente.java:85)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse
(StringRequest.java:60)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse
(StringRequest.java:30)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run
(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-21 08:27:41.042 24791-24791/joinder.proyecto W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es

> JSONException: Value `<br` of type java.lang.String cannot be  converted  to JSONObject

se genera en el método `onResponse()` de la clase Main_docente :

```
   @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
```

y es debido a que lo que insertas parsear no es un JSONObject, al parecer es un contenido html:

```
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

**Debes asegura que response sea un objeto .json**

Comment: Y entonces que debo hacer para solucionar aquel error compañero?

Comment: Es que es muy raro, por que lo unico que le hice al proyecto fue eliminar las variables edad y genero que son las que no necesitaba, antes de eso, el proyecto corrio al 100 en mi telefono y se conectaba a la base de datos perfectamente, no se que pudo afectar en eso.

Comment: Que obtienes aquí? Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString()); la solución es que la respuesta sea un .json, y al parecer estar recibiendo contenido HTML.

Comment: Ya lo encontre :D.   04-21 13:13:05.849 30569-30569/joinder.proyecto D/RegisterActivity: Register Response: 
                                                                    
                                            
                                                                    
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_v2\update_user_info.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />

Comment: Ese es el problema, un error en : update_user_info.php

Comment: Entonces el error es al verificar si el usuario existe, esta es la linea 92 que pone el error en el update_user_info.php : $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

Comment: @ChechoParrado , lo que comunmente se realiza para evitar el error sea propagado, es que la respuesta sea vac[ia n lugar de agregar el error.

Comment: Discúlpame compañero pero sinceramente no entendí lo que trataste de decir, ya estoy por tirar la toalla por hoy. Dejare la pregunta como solucionada. Gracias por haberme ayudado. Cualquier cosa espero encontrarte en el chat :D.