# Estoy insertando registros en android studio, el error está en los msj me no puede convertir string en JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql-workbench

**Este es   mi tabla   tb_usuario**

```
    CREATE TABLE tb_usuario(
    Id_usuario  int auto_increment NOT NULL,
    Code Varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    User Varchar(90) NOT NULL,
    Pass Varchar(90) NOT NULL,
    TipoUsuario Varchar(90) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id_usuario),
    UNIQUE KEY usuario_idx(Code)
   );
```

**Este es  mi Código  PHP**

```
      <?php
          require('conexion.php');
          $Code=$_GET['Code'];
          $User=$_GET['User'];
          $Pass=$_GET['Pass'];
         $TipoUsuario=$_GET['TipoUsuario'];
         // Sentencia INSERT
           $comando = "INSERT INTO tb_usuario ( " .
          "Code," .
          "User," .
          "Pass," .
          "TipoUsuario)" .
         " VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        // Preparar la sentencia
          $sentencia = $conn->prepare($comando);
          $sentencia->execute(array($Code,$User,$Pass,$TipoUsuario));   
          if($sentencia)
           {
             // Código de éxito
             print json_encode(
             array(
            'estado' => '1',
            'mensaje' => 'Creación exitosa')
         );

    }
       else
    {
      // Código de error
      print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '2',
            'mensaje' => 'No se pudo realizar la inserción  por que ya existe  un registro con este código')
    );
   }
 ?>
```

**Este es código android(JAVA)**

```
     public void guardarUsuario() {

    final String Code = et1.getText().toString();
    final String User = et2.getText().toString();
    final String Pass = et3.getText().toString();
    final String TipoUsuario =muestraUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("Code",Code);
    map.put("User",User);
    map.put("Pass", Pass);
    map.put("TipoUsuario", TipoUsuario);

    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

    Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());


    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplication()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    Config.URL_ADD_USER,
                    jobject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            procesarRespuesta(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Esta es la  parte  donde  me muestra  el error,el logcat  me dice que no puede  convertir una variable string en JSONObject.

// *****************************************************************
//******************************************************************

```
 private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

    try {

        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");


        switch (estado) {
            case "1":

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplication(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case "2":

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplication(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Simplemente revisa y asegura response tenga formato de un json, si no es así marcará error. que valor tiene response?

Comment: @Jorgesys me  estoy apoyando de esta web, trato de  implementar  la  parte de  insertar  pero sin fragment. http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/crear-un-webservice-para-android-con-mysql-php-y-json/

Comment: A mi me pasó en una oportunidad, el error era es que mi script php (archivo) estaba en formato ANSI, lo cambie a UTF-8 sin BOM y me fue de maravilla, para ello puedes usar cualquier editor incluso el Bloc de Notas.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar aquí: `Config.URL_ADD_USER, jobject,` el valor `jobject` por `null`. Si no estás enviando nada al servidor, sólo pidiendo, usa `GET` en lugar de `POST`,  además, si sólo recibes datos no tienes que hacer todo el rollo del `getHeaders` y `getBodyContentType`. Yo lo uso en mi app sin eso y me funciona bien. También, imprime en alguna parte la url completa, como la estás enviando al servidor e introdúcela en tu navegador para comprobar que efectivamente devuelve un JSON. Si nada funciona, entonces tendrás que pedir y tratar tu respuesta como un String y convertirla en JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que el logcat te arroja este mensaje: *no se puede convertir una variable string en JSONObject.* es muy probable que la respuesta del servidor no tenga los headers establecidos correctamente, aunque parece que se los estás enviando desde Volley.

Yo para evitar eso, prefiero **no delegar en volley el establecimiento de encabezados**, esto se puede hacer perfectamente si la URL a la que estás enviando la petición sólo la necesitas para otorgar una respuesta del tipo JSON.

En lugar de hacerlo desde Volley, puedes hacerlo desde el servidor de la siguiente manera.

Asumiendo que esta es la parte de PHP que responde a la petición, que envía los resultados de vuelta a Android:

```
if($sentencia)
{
    // Código de éxito
    $arr_respuesta = array(
        'estado' => '1',
        'mensaje' => 'Creación exitosa');

}
else
{
    // Código de error
    $arr_respuesta = array(
        'estado' => '2',
        'mensaje' => 'No se pudo realizar la inserción  por que ya existe  un registro con este código');
}

//Establecemos el tipo de contenido mediante un header en PHP

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
print json_encode($arr_respuesta);
```

Lo que se ha hecho en esa penúltima línea ha sido establecer el encabezado y el encodaje de la respuesta desde PHP.

Ahora bien, para que `header` no te de problemas se recomienda no imprimir  absolutamente nada (mediante echo, print, contenido html u otro) antes de usar `header`.

Si quieres verificar el tipo de respuesta que da el servicio web lo puedes hacer introduciendo en el navegador una prueba de URL tal y como se la enviarías desde Volley e inspeccionando los recursos desde el menú de desarrollo del navegador.

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen verás que el `Content-type` es en efecto del tipo esperado.

Haciéndolo de ese modo, no hay necesidad de toda la historia del método `getHeaders()`

Es de esa forma como uso Volley en mi App y hasta ahora no he tenido ningún problema.

Este sería un ejemplo del código que tengo funcionando actualmente:

```
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
String items;
JsonObjectRequest joRequest;

//Este sería tu mapa
final String Code = et1.getText().toString();
final String User = et2.getText().toString();
final String Pass = et3.getText().toString();
final String TipoUsuario =muestraUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("Code",Code);
map.put("User",User);
map.put("Pass", Pass);
map.put("TipoUsuario", TipoUsuario);

JSONObject jsonMap = new JSONObject(map);



// ....
  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  joRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, OL_URL, jsonMap,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     procesarRespuesta (response);
                }
            },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(joRequest);

 // ....

 private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
       //Código de procesamiento
 }
```

Comment: no entendí  tu código, lo que  pasa  que  lo haces  dentro del  oCreate  y  no creas una  método  para que  dentro de  un Onclick  se  ejecute.¿podrías  explicarme mejor tú código por   favor?

Comment: Ahora te explico. Pero dime una cosa : ¿tú quieres enviar datos al servidor, recibir datos del servidor o ambas cosas ? Es que no queda claro si quieres insertar algo en la BD remota (servidor) o si quieres loguearte en el servidor enviando un usuario y contraseña desde Android. Si me aclaras ese punto podría editar la respuesta comentando el código. También sería bueno que sepas cómo responde el servidor a tu petición si tuvieras un fragmento de la respuesta mucho mejor.

Comment: Buen  día @A.Cedano, lo que intento es  enviar  y recibir datos del servidor, en este  caso  voy a  insertar  registros y después  recibir respuesta del servidor si  los registros se insertaron  correctamente o no  mediante mi  código  PHP PDO. Espero  puedas  ayudarme  saludos.

Comment: @Sofia Dado que he visto muchas dudas al respecto te haré un ejemplo completo sólo que ahora mismo no es posible. Veré si puedo durante el día de hoy. Saludos.

Comment: ,se que el tiempo es lo que  hace  falta pero  en cuanto tengas un ratito  de  tiempo  libre  te agradeceré  que me envíes el código para  insertar que me  comentaste, de  antemano   muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es exactamente el mismo problema que esta pregunta:

[Ayuda con AndroidLoginyRegistro con PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64501/ayuda-con-androidloginyregistro-con-php)

El código de tu aplicación Android, espera recibir un JSONObject para obtener el valor de `estado`, `mensaje` y un JSONArray llamado `metas`:

```
private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        // Obtener atributo "estado"
        String estado = response.getString("estado");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1": // EXITO
                // Obtener array "metas" Json
                JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                // Parsear con Gson
                Meta[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta[].class);
                // Inicializar adaptador
                adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
                // Setear adaptador a la lista
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;
            case "2": // FALLIDO
                String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Pero si la respuesta que recibes no es un json tendras este problema, debes asegurar que tu .php funcione correctamente y que retorne un .json.

Como prueba, puedes sobreescribir el valor de response en el mètodo `procesarRespuesta()` y observaras que el código de tu aplicaciòn funciona correctamente:

```
 private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

    try {
         //Sobreescribe el valor de response.
         response  = new JSONObject("{'estado':'2','mensaje':'No se pudo realizar la inserción  por que ya existe  un registro con este codigo'}");


        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

...
...
```

y trata de usar el `LogCat` por favor para que determines rápidamente los problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trabaja con json debes tener en cuenta las tildes y ñ(s) que siempre dan problema.

Verifica que las cadenas de texto se pasen a UTF8 para luego convertirlas a un json.

Normalmente las funciones que convierten a json un string fallan si los carácteres contenidos no están en UTF8.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede proveer una solución válida al problema, sería bueno que añadieras algo de código que se pudiera aplicar al caso expuesto por el usuario (p.e. la función que pase la cadena de texto a UTF8)