# error no se puede convertir String a JSONObject android studio al intentar actualizar

Tags: php, android, mysql

**Código  PHP PDO**

```
   <?php
   require('conexion.php');

  $Code=$_GET['Code'];
  // Consulta de Usuarios en la base de  datos
    $consulta = "SELECT Code,
                        User,
                        Pass,
                        TipoUsuario
                         FROM tb_usuario
                         WHERE Code = ?";
      $comando=$conn->prepare($consulta);
      $comando->execute(array($Code));
      $row=$comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($row)
      {
 $User=$_GET['User'];
 $Pass=$_GET['Pass'];
 $TipoUsuario=$_GET['TipoUsuario'];

// Creando consulta UPDATE
    $consulta = "UPDATE tb_usuario" .
        " SET User=?, Pass=?,TipoUsuario=? " .
        "WHERE Code=?";

    // Preparar la sentencia
    $cmd = $conn->prepare($consulta);

    // Relacionar y ejecutar la sentencia
    $cmd->execute(array($User,$Pass,$TipoUsuario,$Code));

    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '1',
            'mensaje' => 'Se actualizó  correctamente el  Usuario')
    );
}
else
{
 // Código de  error
     print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '2',
            'mensaje' => 'No se actualizó  por que  no hay un Usuario  con este  código')
    );
```

}

```
 ?>
```

**Mi código Android Java**

```
public void ActualizarUser(final View view)
{
    showLoadingDialog("Actualizando.............");

    // obtener  los valores  actuales de  los controles
    final  String Code=et1.getText().toString();
    final  String User=et2.getText().toString();
    final  String Pass=et3.getText().toString();
    final  String TipoUsuario=tipUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String newURL = Config.URL_UPDATE_USER;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo

    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_CODE, Code);
    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_USUARIO, User);
    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_PASS,Pass);
    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_TIPOUSER,TipoUsuario);

    // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

    // Depurando objeto Json...
    Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());


    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    newURL,
                   jobject ,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                String estado = response.getString("estado");

                                if(estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                    //Actualización  exitosa.
                                    //Procedemos a hacer las operaciones pertinentes
                                    hideLoadingDialog();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se actualizó el  Usuario  con éxito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    // No  existe  registro con ese  código  para  actualizar
                                    hideLoadingDialog();

                                    Snackbar.make(view, "No se actualizó  por que no existe un registro con este  código", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vd))
                                            .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                                }
                                            }).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                            hideLoadingDialog();

                            Snackbar.make(view, "Por algún  otro motivo no se  pudo actualizar : " + error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vd))
                                    .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                        }
                                    }).show();
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

**Este es el error que me  muestra el Logcat al intentar  actualizar**
[image: Este es el error que me muestra al intentar actualizar]

```
05-12 13:29:16.587 1532-1547/system_process V/WindowManager: not Base app: Adding window Window{daf92ed u0 com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql.buscarUpdateUser} at 5 of 11
 05-12 13:29:16.590 2964-2964/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql D/buscarUpdateUser: {"User":"Mariana","Code":"AB67","TipoUsuario":"Invitado","Pass":"admin"}
  05-12 13:29:16.656 2964-3013/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f7e9e0ff000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f7ea6951ae0
  05-12 13:29:16.966 2964-2964/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
  05-12 13:29:16.968 1763-1763/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
  05-12 13:29:16.968 1763-1763/com.android.inputmethod.latin D/RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.
  05-12 13:29:16.990 1154-1154/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
   05-12 13:29:17.036 2964-2964/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql D/buscarUpdateUser: Error Volley: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
   12 13:29:17.072 2964-2964/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
    05-12 13:29:17.072 1763-1763/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
```

Comment: copiarias el error en texto ?

Comment: @federhico te  refieres  a un archivo en word?  si es así  claro  que  puedo enviartelo.

Comment: nono, asi como pusiste el código en java, que copies el error en la pregunta. creo que alcanzo a ver un  "Value <br of type string..."

Comment: Debes buscar correctamente en el logcat, lo que esta en rojo no es siempre de tu aplicación  revisa si encuentras un segmento donde diga "Caused by".

Comment: @federhico, acabo de actualizar el  mi pregunta  con los errores del Logcat.

Comment: Mientras voy viendo de ayudarte podrías sacar la imagen que está horrible :P

Comment: El error dice que no puede convertir 

Value <br of type java.lang.String to JSONObject

Estás segura que no tienes algun error en el php ?

mira éste hilo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64501/ayuda-con-androidloginyregistro-con-php

Comment: @federhico, compartí  mi código  php,  lo probé desde el navegador  y me funciona  muy bien.Puedes  checarlo  y decirme  por favor  si tengo que  hacer  algunos cambios.

Comment: Quizas es porque se trata de un Array, deberías meterlo en un JsonArray, aunque me sigue pareciendo extraño lo del <br , ya que en un objeto json no debería haber tags de HTML

Comment: A mi me pasaba eso mismo, y el error que tenía era por que no estaba enviando los valores en Java y Php en el mismo orden en el que se encuentra en la base de datos MySQL. En la consola trata de buscar los Log para ver dónde te dice específicamente en que linea está el error. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la respuesta no tiene formato .json, esta obteniendo una respuesta que incluso tiene contenido html, por lo tanto no puede ser convertida a `JSONObject` :

```
> buscarUpdateUser: Error Volley: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of
> type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

primeramente asegura que al consultar tu .php en realidad tiene una respuesta .json, incluso pudiera ser un error el texto que se obtiene como respuesta y por esa razón no puede ser convertido a `JSONObject`.

---

El problema es similar al de esta pregunta:

**[ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Value .... of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35655/error-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-con/35720#35720)**

Tienes que analizar la respuesta, la cual tratas de convertir a `JsonArray`:

```
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
```

Revisa la respuesta y dependiendo de eso recuerda que la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> - Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
> - Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.

Por el error obtenido al parecer la respuesta (response) no es en realidad un `JSONArray`.